# Issues with setting a property

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Below is the gist of the system i'm having issues with.  I seem to understand self, ., and :. I just seem to be missing something.  What's happening is that when it calls "Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo()" if I simply print "self" i'll get a table address printed.  If i go a step further and try to print "self.someObject" i get nil,  which shouldn't happen because in Object it has a key someObject which was created at the start in "Object.new(args)" of course if tried to go a step further it wouldn't even be able to go there since its nil. Please Help!!

### Object File

```
Object = {};

ObjectMeta = {__index = Object};

function Object.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Object.someObject = OtherObject.new(args)
    return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta );
end

function Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo()
    --OtherObject instance Should set its attached property to 
    --This instance of Object
    self.someObject.ObjectImAttachedTo = self;
end

--Calls after new to set the ObjectImAttachedTo Property, So it isnt nil
Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo();

return Object;
```

### OtherObject File

```
OtherObject = {};

OtherObjectMeta = {__index = OtherObject};

function OtherObject.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Obj.ObjectImAttachedTo =nil;
    return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta );
end
return Object;
```

### UPDATE

### Scene

```
Scene = {};

ObjectContainer = {};

function Scene.new()

end

function Scene.addObjects()
    local Object= require "Object"
    local StartX = 50;
    local StartY = 20;
    local counter = 0;
    for i=0, 17 do
         ObjectContainer[i] = Object.new({x=StartX,y=StartY});
    end
end

Scene.addObjects();
return Scene
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `Object` does not have a field named `someObject`, though instances returned by `Object.new()` do have that field. These are two different tables, roughly corresponding to a class and one of its instances.

ADDENDUM

With the revised code, `Object` doesn't have the field `someObject` until you call `Object.new()`. So, you must call `Object.new()` before you call `Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo();`. Note that `OtherObject.new()` must be defined before you can call `Object.new()`.

ADDENDUM2 in answer to question "so what would you suggest i do to fix this?"

```
function Object.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Obj.someObject = OtherObject.new(args)
    Obj.someObject.ObjectImAttachedTo = Obj;
    return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta );
end
```

and get rid of `Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo();`

Comment: ok, well even if i put someObect apart of the Object table, "Object.someObject = OtherObject.new(args)" I still end up with the same problem.

Comment: updated the code, the change is in the Object.new(args) function "Object.someObject = OtherObject.new(args)"

Comment: Where is the call to `Object.new()`?

Comment: added the Scene File, where the Objects are being created above. They are being created in the "Scene.addObjects()" function

Comment: so what would you suggest i do to fix this? make someObject outside the function new and pass a new OtherObject as an argument for Object?

Comment: Making some assumptions about what you are trying to do, see addendum 2.

Comment: Thanks for all your help that before you put up your Addendum2 i simply put the call to Object:setSomeObjectIsAttachedTo() in the Object.new function but your suggestion is in fact alot cleaner and gives the same result.  Once again Thank you i really appreciate it!!